# jstat - Any performance impact in production

Tags: java, performance

Is there any performance impact if we keep running **jstat** command (say every 5 min or so) in production environment to monitor JVM (6.x) memory? The target system is a real time application and even one second pause does matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, `jstat` does not impose any noticeable performance impact, even when run every second.

This tool relies on [HotSpot Performance Counters](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/Serviceability.html#bjvmstat) (aka PerfData).
`jstat` basically reads data from mmap'ed `/tmp/hsperfdata_username/vmid`. HotSpot exports these counters anyway, whether you read them or not.